# GIMP: how to combine images where one has transparent parts

Tags: gimp

I have an image where certain parts are deleted and are transparent. I would like paste another image onto this and would like to see it only covering those transparent sections of the original image. What would be the "best" way to do that in GIMP?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Paste it into another layer **underneath** the layer with transparency. I don't use Gimp [I'm Photoshop], so can't tell you exactly how you'd set that up.

Comment: @Tetsujin awesome. haven't thought about that, so simple. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Paste it into another layer underneath the layer with transparency
https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-layer-lower-to-bottom.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).